# How do I share a virtualbox folder on a linux puppy guest?

Tags: virtualbox, guest-additions, puppylinux

I'm trying to find a smaller alternative to ubuntu for virtual machines, but I can't share data between my host system and puppy. When I try to install the guest addons it produces the following errors:

```
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the 
current kernel for adding new hardware support to the system.
VirtualBox Guest Additions: modprobe vboxsf failed
```

Clipboard support seems to work but there are no new folders under 'mnt', the way there was under 'media' on ubuntu.

The puppy package manager also has a virtualbox-guest_dkms package, but it gives a warning that it can't be installed without devx.

How do I get my files onto my new virtual machine?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is missing .sfs files that are not downloaded by the puppy system. Go back to where you got the puppy .iso (http://distro.ibiblio.org/puppylinux/puppy-bionic/bionicpup64/) on the puppy machine and download these files:

```
devx_bionicpup64_8.0.sfs
kernel_sources-4.19.23-bionicpup64.sfs
```

Run them, let them move themselves to /mnt/home/ if you didn't save them to that folder already, and then restart the system for good measure. Then try the guest addons cd again. It should install correctly but you need to setup the mounting yourself. Create the folder you setup in your virtualbox shared folder settings (ex. "c:\puppy_food")

```
mkdir /mnt/puppy_food
```

Then add this line to your /etc/rc.d/rc.local

```
mount -t vboxsf puppy_food /mnt/puppy_food
```

Restart again and the folder should be fully accessible.